# Как я могу получить адрес шлюза на языке swift для iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, сетевое-программирование

Как я могу получить адрес шлюза (ip адрес роутера в сети которого подключено устройство) на языке swift для iOS? В ifaddrs не нашёл, но возможно плохо искал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если без заморочек, то можно попробывать так:

```
private func getIpAdress() -> String? {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://api.ipify.org/") {
        if let result = try? String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**UPD:**

Это для получения своего внешнего Ip адреса.

Comment: Лучше с заморочками, но с помощью устройства получить. Да и соединения с интернетом не всегда может не быть. Спасибо.

Comment: А можно получить как-нибудь адрес именно шлюза (роутера), например 192.168.0.1? И возможно ли такое вообще с использованием swift, находил только реализации с objective-c.

Comment: @lamberdd Любой код на objc можно переписать на Swift. Разместите где-нибудь на code.re, я переведу на Swift